# Python: Suppressing errors from going to commandline?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, html-parsing

When I try to execute a python program from command line, it gives the following error. These errors do not cause any problem to  my ouput. I dont want it to be displayed in the commandline

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 88, in <module>
    p.feed(ht)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/HTMLParser.py", line 108, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/HTMLParser.py", line 148, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/HTMLParser.py", line 226, in parse_starttag
    endpos = self.check_for_whole_start_tag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/HTMLParser.py", line 301, in check_for_whole_start_tag
    self.error("malformed start tag")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/HTMLParser.py", line 115, in error
    raise HTMLParseError(message, self.getpos())
HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 319, column 25
```

How could I suppress the errors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doesn't catching HTMLParseError work for you? If `test.py` is the name of your python file, it's propagated up to there, so it should.

Here's an example how to suppress such an error. You might want to tweak it a bit to match your code.

```
try:
    # Put parsing code here
except HTMLParseError:
    pass
```

You can also just suppress the error message by redirecting stderr to null, like Ignacio suggested. To do it in code, you can just write the following:

```
import sys

class DevNull:
    def write(self, msg):
        pass

sys.stderr = DevNull()
```

However, this is probably not be what you want, because from your error it looks like the script execution is stopped, and you probably want it to be continued.

Comment: When I gave nothing as `Except` argument, It worked. But when I gave `except HTMLParseError:` am getting error `NameError: name 'HTMLParseError' is not defined. So how could I know the exact error thing?
`

Comment: Then you should either catch `HTMLParser.HTMLParseError`, or import it explicitly with `from HTMLParser import HTMLParseError`.

Comment: Oh thanks. I couldnt understand it from the error message. But when I gave `from HTMLParser import HTMLParseError` it worked. But when I gave `HTMLParser.HTMLParseError`, it gave the error `AttributeError: class HTMLParser has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'`. Why is it so?

Comment: You've probably had a `from HTMLParser import HTMLParser` in your code (so the class HTMLParser masked the module HTMLParser). You didn't post the code here, so I was really pushing in the dark. Anyway, I suggest you to read the Python tutorial about [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) and [exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Yes I had. So whats the problem with that?

Answer (score 8):

Redirect stderr to `/dev/null`.

```
python somescript.py 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Is there a programming way of handling it. HTMLParser gives error due to malformed tags. But it doesnt cause any problem for me. Is there any method using `try/catch`

Comment: Depends. Are you writing the program?

Comment: Just a guess, you could put the offending code inside of a `try/except` block.

Comment: Yes I am writing the program. I want to mute the errors since it wont affect the output at all

Comment: Then yes, you would catch the exceptions as explained in the Python tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

In python 3, @Boaz Yaniv's answer can be simplified as

```
sys.stderr = object
```

since every class in python3 is inherited from `Object`, so technically this would work, at least I've tried it by myself in python 3.6.5 environment.

Comment: you need to `import sys` to run this

Answer (score 7):

Here is a more readable, succinct solution for handling errors that are safe to ignore, without having to resort to the typical try/except/pass code block.

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(IgnorableErrorA, IgnorableErrorB):
    do_something()
```