# html not printing out output text

Tags: php, python, html

So i have two codes, one of them is just a simple code that i used to test out some php functions. I'm trying to print out the JSON string into my html, one of the codes is working but the other isn't.

So let's say that we have two sets of codes : first.php & first.py , second.php & second.py

**first.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
exec("C:/Users/hln/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/python.exe C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/first.py", $output);
$someOutput = json_decode($output[0], true);
echo "<h3>" . $someOutput['rightCoordinate'] ."</h3>";
echo "<h3>" . $someOutput['leftCoordinate'] ."</h3>";?>
```

**first.py** looks like:

```
import json
a = 1 + 3
b = 5 + 5

x = {
  "leftCoordinate": a,
  "rightCoordinate": b
}

y = json.dumps(x)
print(y)
print()
```

**second.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
exec("C:/Users/hln/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/python.exe C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/second.py C:/xampp/htdocs/w3layout/finalproject/uploads/10.PNG 10.PNG 2>&1",$output);
$someOutput = json_decode($output[0], true);
echo "<h3>" . $someOutput['theWidth'] ."</h3>"; ?>
```

**second.py** looks like:

```
outputvalues = {
    "leftCoordinate" : x_min(each of these are already defined),
    "rightCoordinate" : x_max,
    "lowerCoordinate" : y_min,
    "upperCoordinate" : y_max,
    "numInjuries" : count,
    "theWidth" : im_width,
    "theHeight" : im_height
}

y = json.dumps(outputvalues)
print(y)
```

when i run them in command prompt, the first one will result:

```
{"leftCoordinate": 4, "rightCoordinate": 10}
```

and when i put it in my html it will print out 4 and 10

the second one have this result in command prompt:

```
{"leftCoordinate": 34.47790487855673, "rightCoordinate": 251.67991018295288, "lowerCoordinate": 208.6769086420536, "upperCoordinate": 388.4499931335449, "numInjuries": 1, "theWidth": 327, "theHeight": 503}
```

but it won't print out any result in html

is there anything that i should change?

Comment: when i echo count($someOutput) on the second code, it gives me 0

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a helpful answer because there does not seem to be anything wrong with your code.

I placed the following at the top of second.py:

```
import json

x_min = 34.47790487855673
x_max = 251.67991018295288
y_min = 208.6769086420536
y_max = 388.4499931335449
count = 1
im_width = 327
im_height = 503
```

and removed the absolute paths in second.php:

```
exec("second.py 10.PNG 10.PNG 2>&1",$output);
```

Now `php second.php` shows me `<h3>327</h3>`.

This is on Windows 10 with PHP 7.3.1 and Python 3.7.4.

Edit: Tried it on Ubuntu 19.04/PHP 7.2.19/Python 2.7.16 and got the same result.

Comment: hey thank you so much for your answer! but turns out the $output is also saving the warning messages created by tensorflow so the outputvalues that i want is actually saved at the end of the array. Do you have any suggestions on what should be changed if i only want those 7 values to be saved in $output?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Python. Perhaps one of the suggestions to disable warnings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925918/python-suppressing-errors-from-going-to-commandline) might work.

Comment: Found it, see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments the problem is the fact that the Python script generates a warning which is then passed to the PHP script.

One way to ignore the warnings is to add the `-W` option with a value `ignore`. The line in the PHP script would then look something like this:

```
exec("python -W ignore second.py", $output);
```